# How to convert a single-threaded R Shiny App to run on a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: r, docker, kubernetes, shiny, shiny-server

**Summary**

How can I transform a single-threaded R Shiny App to operate on a Kubernetes cluster, ensuring that each user accessing the URL is assigned a unique Docker container instance? I currently have a Dockerfile for the app and aim to modify it for Kubernetes deployment, allowing concurrent user interactions without resource constraints. Please advise on implementing Kubernetes for my R Shiny App and utilizing the existing Dockerfile with Kubernetes.

**Context**

I have a single-threaded R Shiny App that currently runs on a local machine or server. However, I want to scale it up and deploy it on a Kubernetes cluster to handle multiple users concurrently. Currently, the app is containerized using a Dockerfile.

My goal is to convert the existing Dockerfile to a configuration that allows the R Shiny App to run on a Kubernetes cluster. Specifically, I want to ensure that each user who accesses the application's URL is provided with a new instance of the Docker container. This way, multiple users can interact with the app simultaneously without any conflicts or resource limitations.

I am seeking guidance on how to implement Kubernetes for my R Shiny App and how to utilize the Kubernetes solution from the existing Dockerfile. Any suggestions or insights on how to achieve this goal would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Each user gets their own container" is generally an anti-pattern.  Neither Docker nor Kubernetes has any sort of out-of-the-box support for it.

Comment: Yes it is Single-tenancy in which a single instance of an application serves one customer but that is key requirements for our banking and financial projects.

Comment: You can use Portainer to individually manage containers.

Answer (score 1):

I would check out [ShinyProxy](https://www.shinyproxy.io).  I am currently using it for its containerization and SAML authentication. They have some [configuration for Kubernetes](https://www.shinyproxy.io/documentation/configuration/#kubernetes), but I haven't checked that out yet.